# How do I not add any additional containers when using AngularJS 1.6 component?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a simple *component* `site-header` in Angular 1.6 (code below: *site-header.js* and *site-header.html*). I use it in my markup as element `<site-header></site-header>` (code below: *app.html*).

The problem I'm having is I would like to get rid of `<site-header>` element container, because that unnecessarily creates 2 containers for my header (code: *resulting HTML*) - `<site-header>` and `<header>` - while I only need 1. I like to have my markup clean and don't want any excessive containers. They may also force me to write additional styles. I'd like to get rid of one of them (code: *desired HTML*).

I tried stripping wrapping `<header>` from *site-header.html* but then Angular gave me error:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: file:///home/robert/programming/e-lektury/e-lektury-web/src/main/webapp/dist/app/components/site-header/site-header.html
Line Number 6, Column 3:
```

### Main question

Could you somehow get rid of 1 of the containers - reduce the number of wrapping elements to 1?

### Additional question

Why is Angular forcing another container wrapping component's template, when you already have a wrapping element, which is a component's declaration (`<component-name>`)?

### site-header.js

```
angular
  .module('site-header', [])
  .component('site-header', {
  controller: function() {
    this.pageTitle = "Page title";
    this.pageSlogan = "Page slogan";
  },
  templateUrl: './app/components/site-header/site-header.html'
}
```

### site-header.html

```
<header>
  <section>
    <h1>{{ $ctrl.pageTitle }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ $ctrl.pageSlogan }}</h2>
  </section>

  <section>
    <!-- Login and register. -->
    <a href="./login.html">Login</a>
    <a href="./register.html">Register</a>

    <!-- Site search. -->
    <input type="search" />
  </section>
</header>
```

### app.html

```
<body>
  <site-header></site-header>
</body>
```

### resulting HTML

```
<body>
  <site-header>
    <header>
      <section>
        <h1>Page title</h1>
        <h2>Page slogan</h2>
      </section>

      <section>
        <!-- Login and register. -->
        <a href="./login.html">Login</a>
        <a href="./register.html">Register</a>

        <!-- Site search. -->
        <input type="search">
      </section>
    </header>
  </site-header>
</body>
```

### desired HTML

```
<body>
  <site-header>
    <!-- NO <header> here! but there could be <header> instead of
         <site-header> as long as there is only one of them. -->
    <section>
      <h1>Page title</h1>
      <h2>Page slogan</h2>
    </section>

    <section>
      <!-- Login and register. -->
      <a href="./login.html">Login</a>
      <a href="./register.html">Register</a>

      <!-- Site search. -->
      <input type="search">
    </section>
  </site-header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the component to a directive so you don't have to use an element, and instead can bind to an attribute:

#### JS

```
angular
    .module('site-header', [])
    .directive('site-header', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: true,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                controller: function() {
                    this.pageTitle = "Page title";
                    this.pageSlogan = "Page slogan";
                },
                templateUrl: './app/components/site-header/site-header.html'
            }
        }
```

#### Main HTML

```
<body>
  <header site-header>
  </header>
</body>
```

#### Resulting HTML

Page title
    Page slogan

Login
    Register

```
<!-- Site search. -->
<input type="search">
```

Comment: That doesn't get rid of additional container - only enables me to pass some HTML into the component's template.

Comment: I updated to use a directive. Had not read thoroughly enough. I think this is what you want now.

Comment: Thanks, I think that would work fine, but I want to avoid using directive here, as I'm experimenting with components based approach in this app. It logically seems to me that the site header is a component and should be declared as so.

Comment: I don't think you can; if you scroll down here (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)  you see restrict: No (restricted to elements only). It looks like Angular2 supports this with a selector. I am sure someone else knows more than I do here..

Comment: Angular2 also has `ngcontainer` directive (https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) which seems to help with such situations, but I see nothing like it in Angular 1.6.

Comment: Your solution is a good work-around achieving what I want. I still leave the question unanswered though, as I'm interested if you can achieve the same results with `component()` instead of `directive()`.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJs 1.x you can't get rid of the component name markup in the resulting html, But you can write the HTML you want in the component template : 
if **site-header.html** =

```
<section>
  <h1>{{ $ctrl.pageTitle }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ $ctrl.pageSlogan }}</h2>
</section>

<section>
  <!-- Login and register. -->
  <a href="./login.html">Login</a>
  <a href="./register.html">Register</a>

  <!-- Site search. -->
  <input type="search" />
</section>
```

and **Main HTML** :

```
<body>
  <site-header></site-header>
</body>
```

You'll have the resulting html you expect i.e.:

```
<body>
  <site-header>
    <!-- NO <header> here! but there could be <header> instead of
       <site-header> as long as there is only one of them. -->
    <section>
      <h1>Page title</h1>
      <h2>Page slogan</h2>
    </section>

    <section>
      <!-- Login and register. -->
      <a href="./login.html">Login</a>
      <a href="./register.html">Register</a>

      <!-- Site search. -->
      <input type="search">
    </section>
  </site-header>
</body>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want, because instead of a **semantic** `<header>` element I am having **unsemantic** `<site-header>`. Still a useful info, thanks.